# Simple hypothesis test for group differences in a longitudinal studies

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, panel-data

I am having data gathered from a longitudinal study, where each participant answered multiple questionaires per day. What I would like to do is a simple hypothesis test (something like a Welch's t-test) to test if the average answers (numerical value) given by different groups (e.g. male vs. female; student vs. workers, etc) differ significantly from each others.

My problem is, that I am not sure about how the fact that we have repeated measurement of each participant affects the applicability of 'standard' tests for difference in means. Usually, I utilized Mixed Linear Models with participant id as random effect, but I would prefer to use a simpler model/test for reporting. My questions are therefore:

1. What are there any pitfalls when applying statistical tests for difference of group mean (such as t-test) naively to such longitudinal data?
2. Do variations of such tests exists, that adresses the within-subject coraviance?
3. If I have to use Mixed Linear Models (with a lmer-formula like `y ~ 1 + sex + (1|subject)`) : The grouping variables of interest (sex etc) do not vary within subjects , does this effect the model?

I'm relatively inexperienced with analyzing longitudinal data; so any advice would be appreciated. :)